# Creating a likes system in mysql using auto increment?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I'm trying to create a really basic like system using auto increment in mysql.

Basically this script inserts the `user_id` and auto increments the like column to 1, what I need to try and do though is once the the `user_id` and like has been inserted the first time round I then need to make my script say something like if result already exists update else insert?

Can someone please show me how I could do this thanks:

```
<?php

require_once('includes/session.php');
require_once('includes/functions.php');
require('includes/_config/connection.php');

session_start();

    confirm_logged_in();

    if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
    $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];


}


if (!isset($_GET['to']))
    exit('No user specified.');

$user_id = $_GET['to'];




$result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_likes (liked_id) VALUES (".$user_to_id.")");


if($result1) 
{ 

header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");

}
?>
```

Comment: PLEASE stop using `mysql_query()`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942

Answer (score 0):

Do a SELECT first to see if ptb_likes contains the row you're thinking about inserting.

Once you know if it does or does not exist you can choose what to do next.